# How to Print String without putting it inside double quotes

Tags: java

This string needs to be printed without using double quotes.

```
 Class Test{
 public static void main(String args[]){

 //print "I am khushi" but it should not be printed like 
 //System.out.println("I am khushi");

 }
 }
```

Comment: single quote and character array :) or ascii math function to get characters for index `x`

Comment: I am not aware of any such method, but I am curious as to why you would even need such a method?

Comment: `System.out.println("\"I am khushi\"");`

Comment: Oh khushi! What wacky adventures have you gotten yourself into now?

Comment: As we know that for printing any string in java we need put it in double quote (" "). So I am looking for the another way where we can print string without putting it inside double quote (" "). Please let me know if still you have doubt in getting my requirement.

Answer (score 5):

```
System.out.println(\u0022I am khushi\u0022);
```

Comment: Awesome solution, have to remember that one! Intellij IDEA goes crazy about syntax though, all red and underlined. Compiles and works all right however.

Answer (score 3):

This?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[] msg = new char[]{73, 32, 97, 109, 32, 107, 104, 117, 115, 104, 105};
    System.out.println(String.valueOf(msg));
}
```

Comment: i think it is a correct solution why down-vote? +1 from me

Comment: Hi Mikhail your answer is correct but is bounded to particular string I have given. If I am taking any long phrase It would be hectic.

Comment: @user3477197 yep, not arguing on that. But the question states: "this string", and sounds like a puzzle from a teacher.. like the one-time puzzle which does not need a general solution.